# How can I prevent Joomla from removing octothorpe/pound from URL post login?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, administrator

For example, I would like to send the following links in an email to users:

1. `https://www.example.com/#foo`
2. `https://www.example.com/deep-link/#foo`

When clicked on, I get the following results:

1. `https://www.example.com/#foo`
2. `https://www.example.com/register/user-information?view=login#foo`

Both make sense. But once I log in, `#foo` is dropped from each URL.

Answer (score 1):

The # and the string after together are called a fragment.  Your question seems to suggest that you expect the fragment to be preserved as you run a post request (such as logging in) but that would be unnatural.  Depending on what you are hoping to achieve you may be better off using a query string in your email link, or setting a cookie when a fragment is present. Perhaps you could edit your question with details of why you want the fragment to be appended to subsequent uris?